# Some HTML codes is not working on IE8

Tags: html

some html codes are not working on my IE8, but works fine on firefox.
one of them is:

```
<center></center>
```

the other one is the align property for images, such as align="absmiddle".

Why it is like this? is there any problem with my own IE, or is it global?

Comment: *IE is global problem* not just your machine :)

Comment: Stupid question, but is there anything between the `<center>` and the `</center>`?

Comment: When someone starts a comment with "Stupid question, but..." it means "I might be stupid for asking this, but..."

Comment: Learn CSS and use that for presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `center` element works on all browsers, but its meaning often differs from what authors expect. Besides, its effect may depend on “standards mode” vs. “quirks mode”, often differently on different browsers.

The value `absmiddle` is nonstandard, it is treated differently in different modes. Using the `vertical-align` property in CSS works usually more consistently.

To get more specific help, you need to show a document or URL where your problem appears. An entire document is needed, not just a snippet, because the mode of a browser depends on the doctype declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Because those HTML elements and attributes are deprecated.

Comment: so If I want to set absmiddle position for an image in IE, what should I do?

Comment: @Stranger `vertical-align:middle` is closest.

Answer (score 2):

It is a global problem that same code don't work fine with all Browser. Basic solution is to use the basic and un-deprecated Tags.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, these tags are deprecated.

You should try using CSS to style your pages, and use HTML only as markup. It's very easy to get to grips with, and your projects will be way more standards-compliant.